# JQuery tree with select/deselect all option

Tags: jquery, tree

I'm wondering how I can add a button (or a parent checkbox) to the following code to do Select All and Deselect All in the checkbox.

```
    function selectVols() {
    $("#volumesContainer").show(); 
    $("#volumesContainer").dialog(); 

    var tree = $('#tree').tree({
        primaryKey: 'id',
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        dataSource: menu,
        selectionType: 'multiple',              
        checkboxes: true
    });

    tree.on('checkboxChange', function (e, $node, record, state) {
        var vol;

        if (state != 'indeterminate') {
            $.each(volumes, function (i, e) {
                if (e.name == record.text) {
                    vol = e;
                }
            });

            if (vol != undefined) {
                if (state == 'checked') {
                    draw(vol);
                }
                else {
                    clear(vol);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I am very new to jquery and there seems to be many ways to do this on the Internet but none are close enough to the code I have been given to get a solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer used here:

added the following above tree.on(

```
$('#treeCheckAll').on('click', function () {
            tree.checkAll();
        });
        $('#treeUncheckAll').on('click', function () {
            tree.uncheckAll();
        });
```

along with the buttons

```
    <button id="treeCheckAll" class="gj-button-md">Check All</button>
    <button id="treeUncheckAll" class="gj-button-md">Uncheck All</button>
```

could do tree.checkAll(); as a click event in the button too.